# UNEXPECTED TOP_LEVEL EXCEPTION Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-library, dex

After I've added the new library to my project, I started to get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       D:\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output D:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\Discounty\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=D:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\Discounty\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

I've looked through loads of similar questions on stackoverflow but didn't find the working solution.

Below's the screenshot of my project stucture and the build.gradle file of the library project (in libs folder), [here's the link for the screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/iTYoyRT.png):
[image]

And here's my root build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the build.grandle from the app folder:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.discounty.discounty"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.yalantis:contextmenu:1.0.0'
    compile('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.4@aar') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile project('libs:swipe_menu_list_view')
}
```

I tried cleaning the project, but it didn't help.

The new library that I've added (swipe_menu_list_view) contains the support-v4 dependency and I don't use support-v4 anywhere else in my project (or at least I think so), but I've read that this error might happen because different versions of the same library are used in one project.

Could you please help me with solving that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens when you are using 2 different versions of the same library.

You can render the dependency tree with the command `gradle dependencies`

In your case:

`'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.6.0'` uses

```
    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
          <artifactId>support-annotations</artifactId>
          <version>19.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

while you `appcompat 21.0.3` uses

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
  <artifactId>support-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>21.0.3</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

You can check if there is a updated version that uses the same 21.0.3 or you can exclude the dependency with:

```
compile('com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.6.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what should I do with this? I mean  I tried to change the `support-annotations` v21.0.3 in my `floatingactionbutton` library, but this didn't help at all.  
So, could you please help me to solve my problem `cause I really don't know what to do?

Comment: Try to exclude this dependency or to check an updated version. Answer updated

Comment: I tried to add the code you provided with v1.6.0 and after that with v.1.9.1 (latest version of fab library) and this didn't work;( Then I tried to run clean&build commands and after that also tried `invalidate caches/restart`, but I still keep getting the same error. Could you tell me please what else can be done?